# induction in congruence modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

I am learning proof by induction in my math class and I am having trouble with this problem dealing with congruences.

Let $s$ be a positive integer. Then $X \equiv \{a,b,c\} \pmod{2^sk}$  implies $X \equiv \{a,b,c\} \pmod{2^{s+1}k}$. By induction we have $X = \{a,b,c\}$.

My thought is that since the statement clearly states that the former implies latter, we don't need any further calculation to imply the induction, but how am I to state in words that this statement is obvious?

Comment: My thought is that by increasing the value of s, we will get X≡{a,b,c} mod 2k implies X≡{a,b,c} mod 4k. And then X≡{a,b,c} mod 4k implies X≡{a,b,c} mod 8k.. and so on..since this is a sequence that goes to infinity, it implies that this congruence holds for arbitrarily high modulo, in other words it must be actual quantity which is X={a,b,c}

Comment: Sounds good to me.